# htaccess allow country domain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, block, country

I would like to block all countries except mine which is Brunei. The domain is .bn

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from .bn
allow from *.bn
allow from *.*.bn
allow from *.*.*.bn
</Limit>
```

My Name Address: smp-85-139.simpur.net.bn so I believe the code below works:

```
allow from *.*.*.bn
```

But i still got forbidden access. Anything missing here?

---

I tried with IP but still blocked..

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 202.152.*.*
</Limit>
```

My IP is 202.152.85.139

---

UPDATE:
It appears my web host is using nginx so this setting won't work at all if I'm right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an .htaccess allow list for Brunei Darussalam, courtesy of [Country IP Blocks](https://www.countryipblocks.net). The data is correct and current as of 4/20/13.

If your hosting company allows you to use .htaccess you can copy and paste the below data into an .htaccess file and load it into your root:

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
allow from 61.6.192.0/18
allow from 103.4.188.0/22
allow from 103.12.208.0/23
allow from 103.16.120.0/22
allow from 103.17.24.0/22
allow from 103.18.172.0/22
allow from 103.20.24.0/22
allow from 118.103.248.0/21
allow from 119.160.128.0/18
allow from 156.31.0.0/16
allow from 158.161.0.0/16
allow from 192.94.122.0/24
allow from 202.12.26.0/24
allow from 202.59.230.0/24
allow from 202.90.36.0/24
allow from 202.93.208.0/20
allow from 202.152.64.0/19
allow from 202.160.0.0/19
allow from 202.160.32.0/20
deny from all
</Limit>
```